# Center my contour values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, alignment

In QGIS have an issue with my contour value labels being pushed to the edge of my map, instead of lining up at the center where they seem to have more space. Does anyone know why this happens for some and not all? Can someone help me to get them all centered? Please see the attached image.

[image: Misaligned Contours]

Comment: What placement properties did you use?